# how to make a <p> tag editable with an attribute

Tags: html, paragraph

I remember that there is an attribute which you can set to a paragraph to make it editable.
I've tried to remember what attribute it is, but failed.

I must to mention that the attribute doesn't make the `<p>` tag an input, just make it possible to edit content in it.

Comment: If you Google "p editable attribute" the first result is literally a correct answer. -1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are thinking of

```
<p contentEditable ></p>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837(v=vs.85).aspx